# Log in System Where Username and password input are compared to the values saved in database

Tags: php, mysql

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    include("conn.php");
    if(isset($_POST['login'])){
    if($_POST['user']=="admin" and $_POST['pass']=="abc123"){
    $_SESSION['user']=1;
    header("location:login.php");
    exit(); }
    else {
    echo "WRONG USERNAME OR PASSWORD";
    }
    }
    ?>
```

> Please convert it so that the username and password will be compared to the database..
> database is dbcom, tbluser with two fields user and pass...
>
> need any reply as soon as possible, running out of time for our project...
> help is highly appreciated, thanks

Comment: Do you ask us to code your application ? That's not the deal, AFAIK. Please show us your code, ask about your problem, or what you don't understand. We will help.

Comment: I can do this for you for £500

Comment: You should store a salt in your db as well, and use some form of hashing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code,hope it will help.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include("conn.php");
    $qry=mysql_query("select * from tbluser");
    $credentials=mysql_fetch_array($qry);
    if(isset($_POST['login']))
    {
        if($_POST['user']==$credentials["user"] and $_POST['pass']==$credentials["Pass"])
        {
           $_SESSION['user']=1;
           header("location:login.php");
           exit();
        }
       else 
       {
          echo "WRONG USERNAME OR PASSWORD";
       }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Just for reference of future readers, all `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and their usage is highly discouraged. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. MySQLi was introduced back in 2004/2005 and simplifies things greatly, so no point in sticking to old-school alternatives.

Comment: No per-user salt? No password hashing? Please don't promote code with weak security.

Comment: great work,, help very well appreciated... thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Try To Like This:**

```
//set vars
$user = $_POST['user'];
$pass = md5($_POST['pass']);

if ($user&&$pass) 
{
//connect to db
$connect = mysql_connect("$server","$username","$password") or die("not connecting");
mysql_select_db("users") or die("no db :'(");
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tablename WHERE username='$user'");

$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);


if ($numrows!=0)
{
//while loop
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
  {
    $dbusername = $row['username'];
    $dbpassword = $row['password'];
  }
  else
      die("incorrect username/password!");
}
else
  echo "user does not exist!";
} 
else
    die("please enter a username and password!");
```

Comment: Dont use mysql_ its deprecated. Does this even work?

Comment: yes,it is definately work

Comment: It is good that you use a hash, but MD5 is really not sufficient anymore.  The hash should also be salted.  We need to work together to promote good security practice amongst web developers.